# Как получить доступ к переменной в .data?

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте! Как получить доступ к переменной в таком коде:

```
.386
.model flat,C
.data
fr dw 2
gr dw 6

.code
proc2 PROC
push ebp ; Пролог
mov ebp, esp ; Пролог

mov ebx,offset gr
mov edx, [ebx]

mov ebx, [ebx-2]; тут уже не правильно работает код...
mov al,bl
mov ah,0

add eax,edx
```

С переменной `gr` всё удачно. А с `fr` никак не разберусь. Как можно получать доступ к множеству переменных?

Можете показать на моем примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы вам сначала не кинуть в регистр адрес, по которому лежит переменная:

```
 LEA EAX, [gr]
```

А потом уже пользоваться этим адресом для чтения значения, на которое он указывает?

Comment: LEA EDX, [gr]
mov eax,[edx]
LEA EBX, [fr]
mov ebx,[ebx]
add eax,ebx 
так? но опять же ерунда, никак не сумма 2+6

Comment: Постоянно в ячейку попадает 00060002, а нужно только 0002...

Comment: Вот! Я сейчас тоже смотрю, как это работает, под дебагером. У меня тоже такая картина, но только, скажем, при gr=5 в EAX оказывается:

   B80005

...

Comment: Ребята, с меня хватит.... Я спать, целый день эту фигню разбирал, спасибо...

Comment: Прошу прощение, в своём ответе бредятину какую-то накатал, поздно уже. Почему юзаете кстате eax и ebx? по идее, раз слово, надо 

mov ax,[edx]

mov bx, [ebx]

xor eax,eax

xor ebx,ebx

add ax, bx

Comment: А кто минус влепил за нормальный ответ?

Comment: @asen, @karmadro4 наверно :)

Comment: ЧТД :)  

    -1
    ответ участника Asen в вопросе Как получить доступ к переменной в .data? 
33 минуты наза

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался))) Утро вечера мудренее!!!!